# how to configure httpsink to set the header content type

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have setup a local kafka cluster and a local microservice endpoint.
What I want is to feed the httpsink with a topic message like `{"foo":"bar"}`
so that it can call the API endpoint with the json str.

I didn't use the schema registry.

below is my confluent httpsink connector config,

```
{
  "name": "httpsink3",
  "config": {
    "name": "httpsink3",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.http.HttpSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "topics": "test3",
    "http.api.url": "http://localhost:5000/out",
    "reporter.result.topic.name": "success-responses",
    "reporter.result.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "reporter.error.topic.name": "error-responses",
    "reporter.error.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "reporter.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
    "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
    "confluent.topic.replication.factor": "1"
  }
}
```

The result is

```
decision-decision-1  | [2022-12-01 15:10:52,500] DEBUG in routes 79: request.headers=Content-Length: 13
decision-decision-1  | Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
decision-decision-1  | Host: localhost:5000
decision-decision-1  | Connection: Keep-Alive
decision-decision-1  | User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.17)
decision-decision-1  | Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
decision-decision-1  |
decision-decision-1  |
decision-decision-1  | [2022-12-01 15:10:52,501] DEBUG in routes 80: request.data={"foo":"bar"}
decision-decision-1  | [2022-12-01 15:10:52,502] DEBUG in routes 86: is json str
```

I expect the output message header set to application/json instead of text/plain

I have also tried use option `"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",`
, but that's even worse, it keeps the text header, but change content to `{"foo"="bar"}`

Any idea to configure this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed. follow this https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/http/current/overview.html#header-forwarding-example

and changed headers option to "headers": "Content-Type: application/json"